# Changing UIImagePickerController Bar Color

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am struggling to change the color of the `UIImagePickerController` library type. Anyone know what I am doing wrong? Not sure why it's yellow, I just want it to look more standard.

**CODE**

```
private func getImage(fromSourceType sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType) {

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(sourceType) {

        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        imagePickerController.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
        imagePickerController.navigationBar.tintColor = .black
        imagePickerController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType
        self.parentViewController?.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: Check extension code in your project

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your AppDelegate.swift?

If you have customize your UINavigationBar barTintColor in AppDelegate, it will effect UIImagePicker's barTintColor as well:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(named: "yellow")
```

Check if there is any code like above and delete it, barTintColor will be back to default color.